# Увеличить количество записей кнопкой на фронтенде. Вордпресс

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Функция get_post() выводит фиксированное количество записей на странице (8). Нужно увеличить это количество при нажатии на кнопку. Желательно что бы увеличение происходило постепенно - что бы каждый раз при нажатии на кнопку количество записей увеличивалось на определенное число. Думал сделать это с помощью JS, но как получить showpost таким образом не понятно

```
$args = ([
'showposts'=>8,
'order'=>'DESC',
'orderby'=>'date',
'offset'=>0,
'category_name'=> $cat
]);
    
$last_posts = get_posts($args);
...
```

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html. Или использовать готовые плагины.

Comment: а  что если вынести $args в JSON и менять значение showposts через js? будет работать?

Comment: Если я верное понял то что Вы хотели сказать, то работать не будет, так как функция `get_posts()` отработает при загрузке страницы и уже вернет результат. Используйте аякс, как и описано в первом комментарии.

Comment: `вынести $args в JSON и менять значение showposts через js` -- ну либо что это значит?

Comment: Я имел ввиду следующее: $args прописать в json-файл , менять его через js и аяксом изменять значение showposts  и  загружать посты. Но теперь вижу что это не сработает. Спасибо за ответ!